# Removing an Observer when it gets Deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, event-handling, observer-pattern

I have the following 2 classes:

EventDispatcher:

```
    @interface EventDispatcher()

    -(id)initEventDispatcher;
    -(NSMutableArray*)getSubscriptionsToEvent:(EVENT_TYPE)eventType;
    -(NSNumber*)getKeyToEvent:(EVENT_TYPE)eventType;

    @end

    @implementation EventDispatcher

    static EventDispatcher* eventDispatcher;

    // Singleton.
    +(EventDispatcher*)instance
    {
        if (eventDispatcher == nil)
        {
            eventDispatcher = [[EventDispatcher alloc] initEventDispatcher];
        }
        return eventDispatcher;
    }

    -(id)initEventDispatcher
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self)
        {
            eventSubscriptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }
        return self;
    }

    // Let anyone subscribe to an event.  Return the EventSubscriber so they can dispatch events if needed, and to be able to unsubscribe.
    -(EventSubscriber*)subscribe:(EVENT_TYPE)eventType :(void(^)(id package))operateEvent
    {
        // Create the object.
        EventSubscriber* eventSubscriber = [[EventSubscriber alloc] initEventSubscriber:eventType :operateEvent];

        // Now get the list it belongs to (we sort subscriptions in a dictionary so that when we dispatch an event, it's fast (we don't need to iterate through all EventSubscribers to find who subscribe to an event).
        NSMutableArray* subscriptionsToThisEvent = [self getSubscriptionsToEvent:eventType];
        if(subscriptionsToThisEvent == nil)
        {
            // If the list is nil, no one has subscribed to it yet, so make that list and add it to the dictionary.
            subscriptionsToThisEvent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSNumber* key = [self getKeyToEvent:eventType];
            [eventSubscriptions setObject:subscriptionsToThisEvent forKey:key];
            [subscriptionsToThisEvent release];
        }

        // Add the EventSubscriber to the subscription list.
        [subscriptionsToThisEvent addObject:eventSubscriber];
        [eventSubscriber release];

        return eventSubscriber;
    }

    -(void)unsubscribe:(EventSubscriber*)eventSubscriber
    {
        // Get the list it belongs to, and remove it from that list.
        EVENT_TYPE eventType = [eventSubscriber getEventType];
        NSMutableArray* subscriptionsToThisEvent = [self getSubscriptionsToEvent:eventType];
        if (subscriptionsToThisEvent != nil)
        {
            [subscriptionsToThisEvent removeObject:eventSubscriber];
        }
    }

    -(void)dispatch:(EVENT_TYPE)eventType :(id)package
    {
        NSMutableArray* subscriptionsToThisEvent = [self getSubscriptionsToEvent:eventType];

        // If no one has subscribed to this event, it could be nil, so do nothing.
        if (subscriptionsToThisEvent != nil)
        {
            // Otherwise, let them all know that the event was dispatched!
            for (EventSubscriber* eventSubscriber in subscriptionsToThisEvent)
                [eventSubscriber dispatch:package];
        }
    }

    // Helper methods to get stuff (lists, keys) from event types.
    -(NSMutableArray*)getSubscriptionsToEvent:(EVENT_TYPE)eventType
    {
        NSNumber* key = [self getKeyToEvent:eventType];
        NSMutableArray* subscriptionsToThisEvent = [eventSubscriptions objectForKey:key];
        return subscriptionsToThisEvent;
    }

    -(NSNumber*)getKeyToEvent:(EVENT_TYPE)eventType
    {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:eventType];
    }

    -(void)dealloc
    {
        [eventSubscriptions release];

        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

EventSubscriber:

```
    #import "EventSubscriber.h"

    @implementation EventSubscriber

    -(id)initEventSubscriber:(EVENT_TYPE)newEventType :(void(^)(id package))newOperateEvent
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self)
        {
            operateEvent = [newOperateEvent copy];
            eventType = newEventType;
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)dispatch:(id)package
    {
        operateEvent(package);
    }

    -(EVENT_TYPE)getEventType
    {
        return eventType;
    }

    -(void)dealloc
    {
        [operateEvent release];

        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

Onto the big question: How do I unburden a programmer who is using this system with having to unsubscribe from an event during deallocation?  When multiple classes are using this system, programmers will have to remember to unsubscribe during deallocation (if not an earlier time), or REALLY bad/weird/unexpected things could happen (I would prefer a compile-time check, or a big, obvious, debuggable crash, but more-so the former).  Ideally, I'd like to restructure this system (or do anything) so that when an object is deallocated, the EventDispatcher gracefully handles it.

One quick fix is to have objects allocate EventSubscribers directly, then in the EventSubscriber constructor, it subscribes itself to EventDispatcher (but that's obviously bad, maybe make EventDispatcher's stuff static? Ugh now we're just getting worse).

Side notes:

I'm not using ARC, but, that does not matter here (at least I think it does not, if there are ARC-based solutions, I'd like to hear them).

I do plan on adding a method in EventDispatcher to be able to remove EventSubscribers by those who did the subscription (so now when subscribing, objects will have to pass 'self').  I also plan on making the enumerated EVENT_TYPE use strings, but that's a different topic altogether.

I also plan on translating a lot of my code (including these classes) to C++.  So I'd appreciate a conceptual solution as opposed to Objective-C specific solutions.

So, is this possible?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: ARC has zeroing weak references. If your subscribers were tracked using zeroing weak references, then you wouldn't necessarily have to remove them at subscriber dealloc time. (You would want to eventually clean up zeroed-out references, but that could be encapsulated in the EventDispatcher.)

Comment: To be clear, the zeroing out only works in ARC correct? Is there a similar concept in C++?

Comment: Zeroing weak references to Objective-C objects are provided by ARC. C++ is not intrinsically reference counted so barring additional code to provide such functionality all references are non-zeroing and weak. You might want to look into `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`.